# How to use a looping operation while performing multiple text replacment using python regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

fo=open('INPUT_FILE.txt','r+')
fo1=re.sub(r'OLD_TEXT_01',"NEW_TEXT_01",fo.read(),re.M)
fo2=re.sub(r'OLD_TEXT_02',"NEW_TEXT_02",fo1,re.M)
fo3=re.sub(r'OLD_TEXT_03',"NEW_TEXT_03",fo2,re.M)
fo4=re.sub(r'OLD_TEXT_04',"NEW_TEXT_04",fo3,re.M)
fo5=re.sub(r'OLD_TEXT_05',"NEW_TEXT_05",fo4,re.M)
replacement=fo5
fo.close()

fo=open('OUTPUT_FILE.txt','w')
fo.write(replacement)
fo.close()
```

"""How do you replace the above code with the help of looping operation
   The input file has OLD_TEXT with number as suffix and this has to be
   replaced with NEW_TEXT with respective number as suffix.This is a 
   manual method working fine but not an automated method"""

Comment: Input and output examples please

Comment: Why replace "OLD_TEXT_01" with "NEW_TEXT_01" five times? Wouldn't doing it once be enough?

Comment: You might not be aware of it, but re.sub does a substitution of *all* matches.

Comment: @Jerry Not as written above because `re.M` has a value of 8 and is used as `count` parameter in the example only max 8 substutions are made. ;-)

Comment: @BlackJack Wow, that was something new to me! I can't believe what I am seeing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the search and replace texts really follow the pattern in the example there's just one `re.sub()` call needed:

```
import re


def main():
    with open('INPUT_FILE.txt', 'r') as in_file:
        content = in_file.read()

    new_content = re.sub(
        r'OLD_TEXT_0([1-5])', r'NEW_TEXT_0\1', content, flags=re.MULTILINE
    )

    with open('OUTPUT_FILE.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(new_content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The variable number part is caught in a group which is used within the replacement text. And also compare the `flags` argument with your code: it has to be the *5th* positional argument or given as keyword argument.

Answer (score 1):

IF I understood the problem... this should help :)

```
import re

in_file=open('INPUT_FILE.txt','r+')
out_file=open('OUTPUT_FILE.txt','w')
patterns = [(r'OLD_TEXT_01','NEW_TEXT_01'),(r'OLD_TEXT_02','NEW_TEXT_02'), (r'OLD_TEXT_03','NEW_TEXT_03'), (r'OLD_TEXT_04','NEW_TEXT_04'), (r'OLD_TEXT_05','NEW_TEXT_05')]

# OPTION 1: Loop to read input file line by line
for line in in_file.redlines():
  for pattern, replacement in patterns:
    line = re.sub(pattern, replacement, line)
  out_file.write(line)

# OPTION 2: Alternative loop that reads in the whole input file (not line by line)
# NOT ADVISABLE FOR LARGE FILES (takes lots of space in memory)
out_put = in_file.read()
for pattern, replacement in patterns:
  out_put = re.sub(pattern, replacement, out_put, re.M)
out_file.write(out_put)


#Close input and output
out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Comment: That `for i in range(len(sequence)):` is an anti pattern in Python. You can iterate _directly_ over the elements, without the index indirection: `for pattern, replacement in patterns:`

Comment: rewrote loop to make BlackJack happy :)